# C++ Derived Class Override Return Type

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, return-type

I think my example below will explain what I am trying to do. I know that I cannot override the return type of the eval() function unless they are covariants, so obviously I am doing something wrong. My question: how do I have a polymorphic base class and derived classes which can evaluate themselves in different ways?

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
  virtual void eval() = 0;
};

class IntNode: public Node {
public:
  IntNode() { val = 0; }
  IntNode(int i) { val = i; }
  int eval() { return val; }
private:
  int val;
};

class FloatNode: public Node {
public:
  FloatNode() { val = 0; }
  FloatNode(float i) { val = i; }
  float eval() { return val; }
private:
  float val;
};

int main() {
  Node *a = new IntNode(5);
  Node *b = new FloatNode(2.3);
  std::cout << a->eval() << std::endl;
  std::cout << b->eval() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: Resolved**

Thank you all for the suggestions. I have figured out a way to accomplish my ultimate goal. In the end I wanted a polymorphic symbol table. I used some of your ideas to get this to work. The biggest breakthrough was to do this "double-sided" plus function. To add two Vars, the first asks the other to add the other with the first's value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Var {
public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
  virtual Var *plus(int i) = 0;
  virtual Var *plus(float f) = 0;
  virtual Var *plus(Var *other) = 0;
};

class IntVar: public Var {
public:
  // constructors
  IntVar();
  IntVar(int i);
  void print();
  // operations
  Var *plus(int i);
  Var *plus(float f);
  Var *plus(Var *other);
private:
  int val;
};

class FloatVar: public Var {
public:
  // constructors
  FloatVar();
  FloatVar(float f);
  void print();
  // operations
  Var *plus(int i);
  Var *plus(float f);
  Var *plus(Var *other);
private:
  float val;
};

// constructors
IntVar::IntVar() { val = 0; }
IntVar::IntVar(int i) { val = i; }
void IntVar::print() { cout << "" << val << endl; }
// operations
Var *IntVar::plus(int i) { return new IntVar(i+val); }
Var *IntVar::plus(float f) { return new FloatVar(f+val); }
Var *IntVar::plus(Var *other) { return other->plus(val); }

// constructors
FloatVar::FloatVar() { val = 0; }
FloatVar::FloatVar(float f) { val = f; }
void FloatVar::print() { cout << "" << val << endl; }
// operations
Var *FloatVar::plus(int i) { return new FloatVar(i+val); }
Var *FloatVar::plus(float f) { return new FloatVar(f+val); }
Var *FloatVar::plus(Var *other) { return other->plus(val); }

int main() {
  unordered_map<string, Var *> symbol_table;
  symbol_table["a"] = new IntVar(5);
  symbol_table["b"] = new FloatVar(2.3);
  symbol_table["c"] = symbol_table["a"]->plus(symbol_table["b"]);

  symbol_table["a"]->print();
  symbol_table["b"]->print();
  symbol_table["c"]->print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kinda feels like the responsibility here is all wrong. What code consumes these evaluations?

Comment: Instead of `eval`, you might have `print` which resolve your example. [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might interest you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

The static type of an expression cannot depend on the dynamic type of an object. Take for instance:

```
auto f(Node& n) { return n.eval(); }
```

What is the type of `f`?

You could resolve your issue with [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) but it would mean the base class knows all types children class could return. This is really a design issue, and you should fix it.

Comment: I kink of hate this, but here is what I did: I added a data member called type and checked which type each variable was to do a cast to the derived class. There must be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer is **you can not**. Overrides in in C++ has to return the same type as original function.

However, a more sophisticated answer is **you can, with some tricks**. One of the tricks would be to use type-erased return value, for example, through `std::any` - see more on it's usage on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

With `std::any`, functions can return any value they want, but it would be type-erased - so callers would have to know what to do with this return value... Which, in a sense, severely limits the applicability scope of this solution. However, there is a place for this as well.

Comment: I'd give good odds that `std::any` is not the right solution for the OP's situation, but since I don't know what that situation is I guess it's fair to point out.

Comment: @TypeIA since OP didn't give us a problem they are solving, I can't comment on this. As a general observation, type-erased return values have their (limited) usage, so I felt it's useful to show this technique.